# C GNU Coreutils: принцип работы tty

Tags: c, gnu, utility

Ниже приведен код утилиты tty на языке С.

Объясните, пожалуйста, принцип ее работы...

```
/* If true, return an exit status but produce no output. */
static bool silent;

static struct option const longopts[] =
{
  {"silent", no_argument, NULL, 's'},
  {"quiet", no_argument, NULL, 's'},
  {GETOPT_HELP_OPTION_DECL},
  {GETOPT_VERSION_OPTION_DECL},
  {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};

void
usage (int status)
{
  if (status != EXIT_SUCCESS)
    emit_try_help ();
  else
    {
      printf (_("Usage: %s [OPTION]...\n"), program_name);
      fputs (_("\
Print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input.\n\
\n\
  -s, --silent, --quiet   print nothing, only return an exit status\n\
"), stdout);
      fputs (HELP_OPTION_DESCRIPTION, stdout);
      fputs (VERSION_OPTION_DESCRIPTION, stdout);
      emit_ancillary_info (PROGRAM_NAME);
    }
  exit (status);
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int optc;

  initialize_main (&argc, &argv);
  set_program_name (argv[0]);
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  bindtextdomain (PACKAGE, LOCALEDIR);
  textdomain (PACKAGE);

  initialize_exit_failure (TTY_WRITE_ERROR);
  atexit (close_stdout);

  silent = false;

  while ((optc = getopt_long (argc, argv, "s", longopts, NULL)) != -1)
    {
      switch (optc)
        {
        case 's':
          silent = true;
          break;

        case_GETOPT_HELP_CHAR;

        case_GETOPT_VERSION_CHAR (PROGRAM_NAME, AUTHORS);

        default:
          usage (TTY_FAILURE);
        }
    }

  if (optind < argc)
    {
      error (0, 0, _("extra operand %s"), quote (argv[optind]));
      usage (TTY_FAILURE);
    }

  errno = ENOENT;

  if (silent)
    return isatty (STDIN_FILENO) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : TTY_STDIN_NOTTY;

  int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
  char const *tty = ttyname (STDIN_FILENO);

  if (! tty)
    {
      tty = _("not a tty");
      status = TTY_STDIN_NOTTY;
    }

  puts (tty);
  return status;
}
```

Comment: Это команда, которая вызывает функции [isatty](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/unistd/isatty.c) и [ttyname](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/unistd/ttyname_r.c) (см. также manpages [man 1 tty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tty.1.html) и [man 3 isatty](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)) для стандартного ввода

Comment: для чего нужен silent?

Comment: silent (`-s`), естественно, для использования в shell-овских скриптах (т.е. когда в скрипте вам надо проверить, но ничего не надо печатать)